# Change contract transaction payer from initiator to contract

Tags: transactions, fees

I have smartcontract that creates some internal structures in external call. Now, when calling this creator function transaction paid by initiator. Is it possible to make contract paying for this tx?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Transaction fees must be paid by the externally owned account that initiates the transaction.